# Python, IoC, Exceptions and loose coupling

Tags: python, exception, inversion-of-control, loose-coupling

Say we have two classes, `Class A` with a custom error which is thrown frequently and it is part of its functionality.

```
#a.py
class AError(Exception):
  """This exception flags a functional error"""
  pass


class A(object):
  def work(self):
    """Throws AError when it is tired"""
    raise AError() #This exception is raised eventually, business code removed for clarity
```

`Class B`, which uses class A to perform some operations.

```
#b.py
import a
class B(object):
  def make_him_work(self, afected):
     try:
       afected.work()
     except a.AError:
       pass #This was expected, here will go some business logic
```

This works great, but it becomes an issue when I have different types of A. Ideally, I'd like to fully decouple A from B so I can pass any class like A that satisfies the same interface, but I cannot due to the exception(as it is not part of the interface itself)

In C++ I would have a header file with the definition of my Interface plus the exceptions which the concrete classes will implement. How is this usually solved in Python? Or said another way, what is the most pythonic approach?

I thought the following options:

---

**1. create module with exceptions and maybe a base class/metaclass (the C++/Java way)**

```
#common.py
class AErrorBase(Exception):
  pass


class AIface(object):
  def work(self):
    raise NotImplemented()
```

.

```
#a.py
import common
class AError(common.AErrorBase):
  pass


class A(common.AIface):
  def work(self):
    """Throws AError when it is tired"""
    raise AError()
```

.

```
#b.py
import common
class B(object):
  def make_him_work(self, afected):
     try:
       afected.work()
     except common.AErrorBase:
       pass #This was expected
```

---

**2. pass exception as an argument**

```
#a.py
class AError(Exception):
  pass


class A(object):
  def work(self):
    """Throws AError when it is tired"""
    raise AError()
```

.

```
#b.py
class B(object):
  def make_him_work(self, afected, ex_type):
     try:
       afected.work()
     except ex_type:
       pass #This was expected
```

---

**3. Exception as an attribute of the Class so it becomes part of the interface.**

```
#a.py
class A(object):
  def work(self):
    """Throws AError when it is tired"""
    raise AError()
  class AError(Exception):
    pass
```

.

```
#b.py
class B(object):
  def make_him_work(self, afected):
     try:
       afected.work()
     except afected.AError:
       pass #This was expected
```

---

**4. Dont use exception, just a return code. !C days are back!**

---

Any other option? What do you find more "pythonic"?

---

Edit: Added comments to clarify the purpose of the exception. It needs to be handled in B

Note: This might perfectly be that I am approaching the problem with my old C++ background, I just want to know how do you apply IoC in python when we have exceptions. Feel free to say all my approaches are garbage and I should do it in another way

Comment: Given that you just `pass` after the error, why throw it at all? Handle it within `A`, and e.g. return `True` (completed) or `False` (stopped for some expected reason) to the caller from `work`. Then you know any error that makes it to `B` is unexpected. Questions like this are quite difficult to answer in the abstract/generic case.

Comment: note business code is removed for simplicity, ``A`` throws because he cannot handle the error but just inform about it and it is within ``B`` where we will have some business code to handle such exception.

Comment: Without a concrete example this question can't be answered, and with one I suspect it would still be on the opinion-based side of things. If you look at standard library modules with specific errors, you could do worse than adopt the convention they use.

Comment: I am just trying to get how a python mature guy solves this kind of issues. I know it might be subjective, this is why I ask what is more pythonic approach.

Comment: the most pythonic would be to raise `RuntimeError('foo')` IMHO. _Simple is better than complex._

Comment: But is it OK if I then catch and check whether it has 'foo'?

Answer (score 1):

My class would look like this:

```
class A(object):
  def can_work(self):
    "returns True if an A can work otherwise False (e.g. is an A is tired)"
    return ...

  def work(self):
    assert not self._is_tired, "Test if self.can_work() first!"
    ...
```

This way you allow the users of A to test whether they should use work.
The assertion is useful for debugging and making sure you or others did not forget about the Interface.

Class B will use A as follows:

```
class B(object):
  def make_him_work(self, afected):
     if afected.can_work():
       afected.work()
```

Comment: But how can I handle the exception in B? When suing assert I just get an ``AssertionError`` I want to have a "meaningful" exception that indicates the handler that something was not working as expected

Comment: There is a difference between something unexpected happened -> Exception and something should not have been done -> violation of contracts/interfaces/assumptions. I will add code for B.

Comment: It is something that is totally fair to happen. Think in B as a network socket, and you want to pass a network error up to your client. But still you dont want your client to depend on a specific implementation of of network socket.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Forget my prev comment

Comment: I think that this is not a Python specific answer. I was taught this as a general design principle to avoid exceptions - which in general should be avoided.